# 404 Not Found: The requested URL /website/Array was not found on this server

Tags: php, mysql

I’m trying to install a web application made in php and mysql.

I load the install.php file into the browser and it ask for a user name and password (for website admin).

After submission it shows the 404 error:

The requested URL /website/Array was not found on this server.

And the error log shows:

File does not exist: D:/wamp/www/website/Array, referer: `http://localhost/website/install.php`

What is that array file??

As for the install.php script, it creates the tables needed in mysql and inserts to it a username and password.

install.php script (SPANISH IS USED)

```
   <?php

/***********************************************************************

Install script

***********************************************************************/

include_once( "config.php" );

if ( isset($send) )
// We have already sent the admin data
{
require("common.php");
// We make avaiable the database
$db = new database()
or die("La base de datos está sobrecargada, por favor intentalo más tarde");

echo "Eliminando las anteriores bases de datos si existieran<br><br>";
$query = "DROP TABLE `League` , `Matches` , `Messages` , `Modules` , `Players` ,           `Teams` , `Users` ;";
 $db->doQuery ($query);

 echo "Creando las bases de datos...<br><br>";

 // Users Table
 $query = "CREATE TABLE Users (uname CHAR(16) NOT NULL, pass CHAR(50), team INT, admin     BIT,";
$query .= "email CHAR(30), language CHAR(5), skin CHAR(16), KEY(uname));";
 $db->doQuery ($query);

 $pass = md5($pass);
 $query = "INSERT INTO Users (uname, pass, admin, email, language, skin) VALUES ";
 $query .= "('$user', '$pass', '1', '', 'es', 'default');";
 $db->doQuery ($query);

 // Players table
 $query = "CREATE TABLE Players (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, name CHAR(30), team INT, uname CHAR(16), defence INT(7),";
  $query .= " pass INT(7), shoot INT(7), keeping INT(7), endurance INT(7), physicalForm INT(7), weeksInjured INT UNSIGNED, matchesPlayed INT UNSIGNED, goals INT, KEY(id) );";
  $db->doQuery ($query);


 // Match table
  $query = "CREATE TABLE Matches (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, home INT,";
  $query .= " away INT, played BIT, scoreHome INT, scoreAway INT, commentary LONGTEXT,";
  $query .= " week INT, KEY(id) );";
  $db->doQuery ($query);


  // Teams table
   $query = "CREATE TABLE Teams (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, teamName CHAR(30),uname CHAR(16) NOT NULL,";
   $query .= " tactic CHAR(8),N1 INT, N2 INT, N3 INT, N4 INT, N5 INT, N6 INT, N7 INT, N8 INT, N9 INT,";
  $query .= " N10 INT, N11 INT, N12 INT, N13 INT, N14 INT, N15 INT,";
  $query .= " leaguePoints INT, KEY(id) );";
  $db->doQuery ($query);


  // League table
  $query = "CREATE TABLE League (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, week INT, KEY(id));";
  $db->doQuery ($query);

  $query = "INSERT INTO League (id,week) VALUES ('1','0')";
  $db->doQuery ($query);


  // Modules table
  $query = "CREATE TABLE Modules (id CHAR(20) NOT NULL, name CHAR(30),";
  $query .= " type INT, KEY(id) );";
  $db->doQuery ($query);

  // Insert modules values
  $query = "INSERT INTO Modules (id, name, type) VALUES ('calendar',";
  $query .= " 'Calendario', 1)";
  $db->doQuery ($query);

 $query = "INSERT INTO Modules (id, name, type) VALUES ('change_profile',";
 $query .= " 'Editar perfil', 1)";
 $db->doQuery ($query);

 $query = "INSERT INTO Modules (id, name, type) VALUES ('roster',";
 $query .= " 'Alineacion', 2)";
 $db->doQuery ($query);

 $query = "INSERT INTO Modules (id, name, type) VALUES ('next_week',";
 $query .= " 'Avanzar jornada', 0)";
  $db->doQuery ($query);

  $query = "INSERT INTO Modules (id, name, type) VALUES ('add_user',";
 $query .= " 'Añadir usuario', 0)";
 $db->doQuery ($query);

  $query = "INSERT INTO Modules (id, name, type) VALUES ('reset_league',";
  $query .= " 'Resetear liga', 0)";
  $db->doQuery ($query);

  $query = "INSERT INTO Modules (id, name, type) VALUES ('standings',";
  $query .= " 'Clasificacion', 1)";
  $db->doQuery ($query);

 $query = "INSERT INTO Modules (id, name, type) VALUES ('private_messages',";
 $query .= " 'Mensajes Privados', 1)";
 $db->doQuery ($query);

 $query = "INSERT INTO Modules (id, name, type) VALUES ('manage_users',";
 $query .= " 'Administrar usuarios', 0)";
 $db->doQuery ($query);

 // Private Messages Table
 $query = "CREATE TABLE Messages (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, messagefrom CHAR(30),";
  $query .= " messageto CHAR(30), subject CHAR(50), body LONGTEXT, internal BIT,  KEY(id) );";
  $db->doQuery ($query);


  echo "Creación completa. Borra el archivo install.php y ya puedes entrar con tu nuevo usuario.";
  echo "¡Disfruta del juego!";
 }
 else
 {
  ?>
 <h1>Instalador de SITE</h1><br><br>
  Introduzca un nombre de usuario y una contraseña para el administrador:<br>
  <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER; ?>">
  Nombre de usuario: <input type="text" name="user"><br>
  Contraseña: <input type="password" name="pass"><br><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Enviar" name="send">
 </form>

  <?php

 }
 ?>
```

Any help will be appreciated
Thank you

Comment: You're in a better position to answer your question than we are, since you have the source code and we don't. Look in the referer, install.php, and find where it refers to Array. Then you'll know what it is, how it is used, and perhaps get some hints on where it comes from.

Comment: There is no reference to Array in the script.
Could it be a related function or something else?

Comment: It's impossible for anybody other than yourself to tell - you have the code and we don't. If you're getting the message that the file doesn't exist, and the referer is install.php, that's the place to look. If it isn't referenced in install.php, look at any includes that install.php makes. Error log messages are rarely wrong about these things.

Comment: Please add the install.php to this question, otherwise its impossible.

Comment: HELP GUYS
i have to change $_SERVER for what??

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in the line

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER; ?>">
```

The $_SERVER is an array, and when you try to print it, all you get is "Array".
From what I understand, you are trying to post the form to the same page, so you can just remove the action attribute. If not, just provide the URL you want and avoid using the $_SERVER, unless you want to edit the URL somehow (like adding https, or similar)

Comment: I'm using wamp, and the install.php file is loaded 1 time to creat an admin user name and password, so i can't remove the action attributed.

Comment: Where do you want to redirect the user, then, when the form is posted? You should use that URL, not the $_SERVER array.

Comment: so can i change $_SERVER by (http://localhost/website/) ????

Comment: any help i don't know what to do

Comment: The form action attribute should post to the .php file that you want to receive the data of the form. You don't have to write an absolute URL, if you want this to work on other environments. You can just write <form method="POST" action="index.php">

Comment: the data will be send to a database in mysql

Comment: Reading the code again, you should just remove the action attribute. If you do not want to do that, just write action="install.php"

Comment: What was the result you had? It couldn't be the same.

Comment: it's the same error......i still don't know what to do

Comment: Can you edit the question and add the code how it looks now?